# Can you have a capacitor app invoke passkey on iOS?

Tags: ios, capacitor, webauthn, passkey

I am trying to make a capacitor app that uses webauthn and invokes passkey on iPhone. Is this possible, does it require any plugins?

I tried just making fetch calls to my webauthn web server. It works on browser on iPhone and web, just not through mobile app. It gets hung up on the create credentials fucntion.

Comment: Are you able to get passkey working on iOS?